# Customizing loading animation using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a plugin for loading animation. Here is my example:

```js
let loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loading')[0];

let width = +loading.style.width.split('px')[0], x = width / 50;

let O = {};
for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    O[i] = {
        left: `0`,
        width: `${i * x}px`
    }
}

for (let i = 50, m = 1; i > 0; i-- , m++) {
    O[m + 50] = {
        left: `${m * x}px`,
        width: `${(i - 1) * x}px`
    }
}

let style = document.createElement('style');

let css = '';

for (let o in O) {
    let c = O[o];
    
    css += `${o}% { margin-left: ${c.left}; width: ${c.width} }`;
}

style.innerHTML = `@keyframes loading{ ${css} }`;

document.head.appendChild(style);

loading.style.animation = 'loading 2s infinite';
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.loading {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="loading" style="width: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

It's working. I want to upgrade this plugin by expanding the container width and keeping the loading width (still `200px`).

```js
let loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loading')[0];

let width = +loading.style.width.split('px')[0], x = width / 50;

let O = {};
for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    O[i] = {
        left: `0`,
        width: `${i * x}px`
    }
}

for (let i = 50, m = 1; i > 0; i--, m++) {
    O[m + 50] = {
        left: `${m * x}px`,
        width: `${(i - 1) * x}px`
    }
}

let style = document.createElement('style');

let css = '';

for (let o in O) {
    let c = O[o];
    
    css += `${o}% { margin-left: ${c.left}; width: ${c.width} }`;
}

style.innerHTML = `@keyframes loading{ ${css} }`;

document.head.appendChild(style);

loading.style.animation = 'loading 2s infinite';
```

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.loading {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="loading" style="width: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

How to let it run to the end of the container?

My default example is easier because the loading width equals to the container width. So, spliting the width to multiple block (mini-widths) by `width / 50` (twice).

Now, if the container width is `300`, and the loading width is still `200`. How to split it?

Thank you!

Comment: change the 50 into 3 different vars and change each one at a time

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! I'm trying...

Comment: If you're dynamically generating a stylesheet, you might be interested in checking out [`CSSStyleSheet#insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) which would make your code easier to read and write.

Comment: @mplungjan I have an answer but your idea. Can you help me more? I want to end the second loop at `100%`, no need to add that field alone. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My idea: Split the container width to 3 parts:

```
                50%
|----------|-----|-----|----------|
{ loading1 }{ 1 }{  2  }{ loading2 }
```

The `m` variable is enabled and increased after getting full the loading width (`1`).

Inside the part `2`, if `m * z + loading_width < max_left` (the `loading2` is larger than the loading width (`200` by default)), keep the width. Otherwise, decreased the width.

Also, because the second loop doesn't stop at `100%`, I have added that field to the css alone:

```
100% { margin-left: 0; width: 0; }
```

```js
let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

let loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loading')[0];

let container_width = +container.style.width.split('px')[0];

let loading_width = +loading.style.width.split('px')[0];

let max_left = container_width - (container_width - loading_width);

let z = container_width / 50;

let O = {};

let m = 1;

for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    if (i * z <= loading_width) {
        O[i] = {
            left: `0`,
            width: `${i * z}px`
        }
    } else {
        O[i] = {
            left: `${m++ * z}px`,
            width: `${loading_width}px`
        }
    }    
}

for (let i = 50, k = 51, n = 1; i > 0; i-- , k++ , n++) {
    if (m * z + loading_width <= max_left) {
        O[n + 50] = {
            left: `${m++ * z}px`,
            width: `${loading_width}px`
        }
        
    } else {
        O[n + 50] = {
            left: `${m * z}px`,
            width: `${container_width - (m * z)}px`
        }

        if (!(container_width - m * z)) {
            break;
        }

        m++
    }
}

let style = document.createElement('style');

let css = '';

for (let o in O) {
    let c = O[o];
    
    css += `${o}% { margin-left: ${c.left}; width: ${c.width} }`;
}

style.innerHTML = `@keyframes loading{ ${css} 100% { margin-left: 0; width: 0; } }`;

document.head.appendChild(style);

loading.style.animation = 'loading 2s infinite';
```

```css
.container {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.loading {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="loading" style="width: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```